# Проблема со скомпилированным проектом Unity

Tags: c, unity3d

### Unity Builded Project Problems | Проблема со скомпилированным проектом Unity

Всем привет, запилил магазин для своей игры, в Unity я нажимаю на кнопку и происходит покупка нового бекграунда, то есть = происходит замена спрайта в префабе бекграунда на новый, купленный спрайт. (1,2 картинки)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WUYB.jpg)[image: 2]
Все выполняется в пару строчек кода, имена спрайтов "1" "2" "3" и тд. имена баттонов для покупки анологично "1" "2" "3" и тд.

Проблема = В Unity все работает отлично = спрайты меняются, покупки происходят, но в сборке проекта не работает ничего, спрайты не меняются, хотя покупка происходит. Проверил на парс, в сборке все парсится правильно(3 пик), Как пофиксить? 
[image: 3]

Comment: Именно в префабе меняешь? или уже в объекте на сцене?(префаб, выложенный на сцену, тоже считается объектом на сцене). Если в именно в префабе, то это не работает на сборке(билде)

Comment: Именно в префабе, с чем это связано?

Comment: Потому что префабы сжимаются в бинарник и уже не изменить